# How did OF. peindre derive from L. pingere, with a "-ng-" > "-nd-" change?

Tags: etymology, sound-change

***[peindre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peindre#Etymology)***

> From Latin **pingere**, present active infinitive of **pingō** (“I paint”).

I am curious about the sound change within the early Romance languages, while this one above maybe not a sound change for its bizarre phonological shift.

Although its just my guess, I still wonder whether it is a regular sound change or not.

Comment: OF *pleindre* is derived from Latin *plangere*, so ng < nd seems not terribly uncommon. And a change from velar to alveolar was also mentioned in your question on [aticum > age](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/how-does-age-come-from-l-aticum-with-a-change-from-t-to-g?rq=1).

Comment: This is indeed a regular change, cf. also *teindre* *joindre* from Latin *tingere* *jungere* etc.: specifically, /ngr/ > /ndr/ in the history of French.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Latin /g/ has anything to do with the French /d/, actually. French generally shows epenthetic /d/ between historic /n/ and /r/ (although there are some exceptions, such as *vinrent* and *tinrent,* and some words such as *genre* that appear to be exceptions). Consider that *tenir,* which never had a /g/, has the future stem *tiendr-*. It's the same sort of sound change that gave us "d" in English *[thunder](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/how-does-the-word-thunder-get-the-letter-d?rq=1)* from Old English  *þunor.*

I don't know for sure, but based on the stem of this verb having /ɲ/ when it's not before "r", I would guess the development from Latin was something like [piŋgɛrɛ] > [peɲɟɛrɛ] > [peɲɛrɛ] > [peɲrɛ] > [pejnrə] > [pejndrə].

A change of Vulgar Latin /ŋɡʲ/ > /nj/ > /ɲ/ is listed on the Wikipedia article "[Phonological history of French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Proto-Gallo-Ibero-Romance)" under the section "To Proto-Gallo-Ibero-Romance". A later change it lists under "To Early Old French" is "Palatal /ɲ/ [is] depalatalized to /n/ [...] following [sic] a consonant. /ɲ/ > /jn/ when depalatalising". I assume the author intended to write "preceding a consonant."

There is no general change of Latin *-ngr-* to French *-ndr-.*
There are words that contain "ngr" in Modern French from Latin "ngr", such as *[palangre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/palangre)* which the CNRTL says is from Latin **panangrum* or *[congre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/congre)* which it says is probably from Latin *congrus.*

Comment: Yes, it is epenthetic /d/ between a nasal and a subsequent /r/. There are actually very few exceptions (I believe *genre* is not one of them, this seems to be relatinisation of the earlier regular *gendre*; the only exceptions I can think of are 3PL past perfect of *venir/tenir* - *ils vinrent/tinrent*, which is probably due to the end-word environment) and the same thing happens with /l/ (*simulare/sembler*, *tremulare/trembler* etc.).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the -e- is lost, then ng assimilates to nd before r. I don't know what the rest of the paradigm looks like, though (because this particular sound change could only take place in the infinitive) - if there's nd elsewhere, I'd wonder if some analogy hadn't happened.

Comment: There is no *nd* elsewhere: *tu peins*, *nous peignons* etc.